# Datagridview Error:: Index was out of range. How I can Solve it?

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access, datagridview, oledb

I have this form application project. I upload a snap of the sales field. Two `datagridview` are there. Bottom `datagirdview` contain `TAX details`. Contain of bottom `datagrid` came from `database except “Amount” column`.  Amount column value provided by user or auto calculated. I write a code. When I try to execute it shows a error. `Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.Parameter name: index`. How Can I solve it??

Snap::

[image]

Here is the code:

```
        private void dgvSalesFooterAdd_CellStateChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellStateChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            decimal Total = 0;

            decimal a=Convert.ToDecimal(lblTotalAdd.Text);
            for (int i = 0; i <dgvSalesFooterAdd.Rows.Count ; i++)
            {

                dgvSalesFooterAdd.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value = a + (a * (Convert.ToDecimal(dgvSalesFooterAdd.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value)/100));

                Total += Convert.ToDecimal(dgvSalesFooterAdd.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value);
            }
            lblFinalTotalAdd.Text = Total.ToString();
        }
```

[NOTE: Error on

```
dgvSalesFooterAdd.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value = a + (a * (Convert.ToDecimal(dgvSalesFooterAdd.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value)/100));
Total += Convert.ToDecimal(dgvSalesFooterAdd.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value);
```

this two lins.]

Comment: looks like it can't throw the exception, unless you made some typo in which `j` was used as `index` instead of `i`. BTW, **what was `j` for**?

Comment: @KingKing: I used j just for testing. Omit it. Ok I'll update it

Comment: Hard to see what could be wrong.  What do you see when you **debug** this?  How many rows/cells are there?

Comment: @Halvard:: Project runs fine expect this page. In this datagridview there are 5 column. Rows size not fixed.

Answer (score 0):

```
  dgvSalesFooterAdd.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value = a + (a *(Convert.ToDecimal(dgvSalesFooterAdd.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value)/100));
Total += Convert.ToDecimal(dgvSalesFooterAdd.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value);
```

it will throw an exception because you are reading the value of 4th column which is null, because cell_value changed worked once you leave the cell...

got throught this link it will give you a better picture..
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvaluechanged.aspx

and try you code like this..

```
 void dgvSalesFooterAdd_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender,
EventArgs e)
 {
if (dgvSalesFooterAdd.IsCurrentCellDirty)
{
    dgvSalesFooterAdd.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
}
}

  private void dgvSalesFooterAdd_CellStateChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellStateChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        decimal Total = 0;

        decimal a=Convert.ToDecimal(lblTotalAdd.Text);
        for (int i = 0; i <dgvSalesFooterAdd.Rows.Count ; i++)
        {

            dgvSalesFooterAdd.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value = a + (a * (Convert.ToDecimal(dgvSalesFooterAdd.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value)/100));

            Total += Convert.ToDecimal(dgvSalesFooterAdd.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value);
        }
        lblFinalTotalAdd.Text = Total.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: if so it should be `NullReferenceException` not `IndexOutOfRangeException`.

Comment: i didn't check for exception but cell_value changed will commit values once user control leaves that cell.. and as per code provided by Animesh Ghosh is trying to read the values which is not commited ..hence it will throw an exception

Answer (score 0):

The exception is thrown when it does not find the Row index in `i`. You will have to reduce the number of rows by 1. This will tell the loop to count only the rows filled by values. Change the line

```
int i = 0; i <dgvSalesFooterAdd.Rows.Count
```

to

```
int i = 0; i <dgvSalesFooterAdd.Rows.Count - 1
```

Complete block will look like this;

```
        for (int i = 0; i <dgvSalesFooterAdd.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {

            dgvSalesFooterAdd.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value = a + (a * (Convert.ToDecimal(dgvSalesFooterAdd.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value)/100));

            Total += Convert.ToDecimal(dgvSalesFooterAdd.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value);
        }
```